# Failed to create directory /Volumes/Android Studio

Tags: android, macos, sdk, android-studio

When I try to install the Android SDK via Android Studio I get his error in the SDK Manager Log I HAVE A MAC not a windows machine.

```
Downloading Android SDK Build-tools, revision 18.1.1
Failed to create directory /Volumes/Android Studio 135.1078000/Android Studio.app/sdk/temp
Downloading Android SDK Build-tools, revision 18.1
Failed to create directory /Volumes/Android Studio 135.1078000/Android Studio.app/sdk/temp
Downloading Android SDK Build-tools, revision 18.0.1
Failed to create directory /Volumes/Android Studio 135.1078000/Android Studio.app/sdk/temp
Downloading Android SDK Build-tools, revision 17
Failed to create directory /Volumes/Android Studio 135.1078000/Android Studio.app/sdk/temp
Downloading Android Support Repository, revision 5
```

So I'm unable to download any of the SDK's :(

Comment: Just close SDK manager and Right Click --> Run as Administrator --> then try again

Comment: @RDC sorry forgot to mention that I have a Apple computer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Fixed it,

Move your android studio installer file to the Applications folder then when it opens choose to install the sdk on default location not in the downloads map (which I did)

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this problem by copying the `AndroidStudio.app` and paste it in your Applications folder then run your `AndroidStudio`. :)

Answer (score 0):

To anybody else who has recently encountered this. If android studio is not able to create or rename files while attempted an update, find where the SDK directory is on your computer. After locating the SDK directory change the read/write permissions for all users. Right click--> get info, and change the privilege to "Read & Write" for all users. Next click the settings icon in the lower left hand corner and click "Apply to all enclosed". After that, you should be able to update any files in Android Studio! (FOR MAC USERS)